# FluentFTP GetListing doesn't return any result

Tags: c#, ftps, fluentftp

I seem to be unable to get any listing from / of the FTP server. (FileZilla is showing the directories and files).

I got this code:

```
                FtpClient ftpConn = new FtpClient();
                ftpConn.Host = FtpServer;
                ftpConn.Port = FtpPort;
                ftpConn.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(Username, Password);
                ftpConn.SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12;
                ftpConn.EncryptionMode = FtpEncryptionMode.Implicit;
                ftpConn.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(Client_ValidateCertificate);
                ftpConn.BulkListing = false;
                //ftpConn.DataConnectionType = FtpDataConnectionType.AutoPassive;
                ftpConn.Connect();

                FtpListItem[] FtpFolders = null;

                FtpFolders = ftpConn.GetListing(Folder);
```

But it doesn't work. I tried the FTP options but didn't get any result.
Any more suggestions?

Comment: What FTP mode is used when FileZilla connected to the remote server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your code,
You can't get any result because of fail to connect to FTP server.

Here is what you missed, refer to this: [FAQ section of FluentFTP](https://github.com/robinrodricks/FluentFTP#faq_certs).
You may have certificate(*.crt, *.cer) file, bring it into your source code as below.

```
ftpConn.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(@"C:\ftpServer.crt"));
```

If your certificate file doesn't have root chain. 
(for example, made by your self or in case of it is private cert file).
You need to add more specific code at,

> ftpConn.ValidateCertificate += new FtpSslValidation(**Client_ValidateCertificate**);

```
private void Client_ValidateCertificate(FtpClient control, FtpSslValidationEventArgs e)
{            
    if (e.PolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.None || e.Certificate.GetRawCertDataString() == "Use this condition for your situation")
    {
        e.Accept = true;
    }
    else
    {
        if (e.PolicyErrors == SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors)
        {
            //In this case, you need to choose connect or not. If your certificate file doen't have root chain.
        }
        else
        {
            //throw new Exception($"{e.PolicyErrors}{Environment.NewLine}{GetCertificateDetails(e.Certificate)}");
        }
    }
}
```

PS : If your FTP service on Windows, you don't have any choice but if it work on linux or unix, You can use SFTP with "Renci.SshNet.

UPDATED : Now windows is support to openSSH, so we can use sftp.
[Installation of OpenSSH For Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/ko-kr/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse)

Comment: I think it is a problem that there is no root chain. I will give your solution a change tomorrow.

Comment: It didn't work.
Due to pressure from the client, I changed to WinSCP. Which worked like a charm.

Comment: Why is this accepted as an answer if it didn't work?